# NSNotification function cannot be called

Tags: function, swift2, nsnotificationcenter

I have a NSNotification function that is giving me an error when called. How can I fix this?

This is the error that is being thrown:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSNotification).Type' (aka 'NSNotification,Type') to be expected argument type 'NSNotification'

Affected code block:

```
@IBAction func loginBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let loginobj = Login(userName : self.usernameField.text!, passWord : self.pwdField.text!)
    loginobj.getRequest()
    handlingAuthentication(NSNotification)

}
```

This is the function that is being called

```
func handlingAuthentication(notification: NSNotification) {

    let errorDectected = notification.object as! Bool

    if(errorDectected){
         //initialize Alert Controller
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication error", message: AuthHelpers.sharedInstance.errorMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        //Initialize Actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default){
                (action) -> Void in
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }

        //Add Actions
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        //Present Alert Controller
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {
        print("error not found")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

    }

}
```

Code where NSNotification is initialised:

```
var error = "true"
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("errorFound", object:error)
```

I'm not sure if it's correct but when I want to change the value of *error* I would just do this `error = false`

Screenshot of error thrown:
[image: Error thrown]

Comment: can u elaborate your question to me exactly what happened?

Comment: It's alright I've managed to solve it. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to add

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("errorPresent", object:errorDict)
```

at the bottom of my function `getRequest()` in Login.swift to post the notification and

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.handlingAuthentication(_:)), name:"errorPresent", object: nil)
```

in my LoginViewController code to receive the notification as well as

```
 func handlingAuthentication(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict = notification.object as! NSDictionary
 }
```

to deal with the data passed